# Get value from model

Tags: django, django-models

I have 2 issues.

First, I have the model with field obj_id, text, creation_date.

In table it looks like:

obj_id text creation_date

```
1      '1'  01.01.2016
1      '2'  01.02.2016
2      '3'  01.03.2016
2      '4'  01.04.2016
```

I need return **list** of 'obj_id' with MAX 'creation_date'.

After that I need execute SQL

```
select * from someModel where obj_id in (list)
```

How I can do it using best Django practices?

P.S. There aren't any relations between two models.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
    someModelobject = someModel.objects.order_by('creation_date')
    objList = []
    for data in someModelobject:
        objList.append(data.id)
```

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't work. **someModelobject** contains only 1 record. And this statement **objList.append(data.id)** return an error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: What do you mean by MAX 'creation_date'. Max or Latest..??

Comment: I mean Latest. I need return latest object. I my case I need return two records **1      '2'  01.02.2016** and **2      '4'  01.04.2016**

Comment: latest also returns ony 1 record with latest creation_date value. I need group_by **obj_id** ((((

Comment: ohh let me try once again :)

Comment: This code return all values just order_by 'creation_date'. I need return only one record for each id with max 'creation_date'

Comment: ??? Then Please update the question  and tell the table structure and include the code for full overview and answer.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be a problem, you can try to use max value from query set of obj_id to generate range for querying and then get latest date from each query:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
    result=[]
biggestID=someModel.objects.latest('obj_id') 
#someModel.objects.all().aggregate(Max('obj_id'))

for i in range(biggestID.obj_id)
   try: 
    val=someModel.objects.filter(obj_id=i).latest('creation_date')
   except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    val=None 
   if val is not None:   
     result.append(val)
```

You also could try:

```
someModel.objects.values('obj_id').annotate(creation_date=Max('creation_date'))
```

I want to point this out, you probably know that, but if you use your obj_id as primary key this won't work, because primary key should be unique.